# Get-CsUserSession StartDate parameter error & credentials without being prompt for a password

Tags: powershell

**EDIT:**

1. I want to retrieve session data from a specific account using
   PowerShell. According to this documentation:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csusersession?view=skype-ps
   `Get-CsUserSession` command is able to do this. I am using this
   command according to the upper's link example

   ```
   Get-CsUserSession -User account@companyX.onmicrosoft.com -StartDate "6/1/2018 07:00 PM"
   ```

   and then I am getting the following error:

   ```
   A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'StartDate'.
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-CsUserSession], ParameterBindingException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.Hosted.Data.GetCsUserSessionCmdlet
       + PSComputerName        : admin1e.online.lync.com
   ```

   What is wrong with that and what is the correct declaration?
2. I am making a connection to Skype for business service with the following script:

   `$credential = Get-Credential 
   Import-Module MSOnline 
   Connect-MsolService -Credential 
   $credential Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector 
   $lyncSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential 
   $credential Import-PSSession $lyncSession`

What I would like to do is to set using a particular static account and password from the PowerShell script (using some sort of declaration variable strings), instead of running this command and have to type the credentials in a separate window.  Meaning that I want to avoid using `$credential = Get-Credential` command. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [documentation you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/skype/get-csusersession?view=skype-ps) (only at the top paragraph though), you have to use `StartTime` not `StartDate`. The error you receive is the typical symptom that you either has a typo in parameter name or this parameter doesn't exist for that function.

I'll request to change the example in the docs a bit later, seems like someone who wrote them were mixing up with another cmdlet.

Edit: to store credentials you can export your password like this:

```
"P@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File C:\Users\username\password2.txt
```

And then import like this:

```
$password = Get-Content -Path "C:\Users\USUARIOPC\password2.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential("yourlogin@domain.com", $password)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is indeed what was missing. Could you please have a look at my edited question?

Comment: Hey, I just added this as it was pretty easy to explain. However, I don't think that's the correct way to proceed (editing your question to ask another one). For the future please create another question for such situation. It'd be more clear for someone who will read this after some time and therefore useful for others, not only for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I edited the title of the question to be more clear.

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure if I was clear but I added the info how to get rid of Get-Credential and save password in file - you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I tried the following query. Probably is not too safe to use a password in a script but for us who want to do it like this is a nice solution.

```
$username = "account1@companyX.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "abcdefg"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

$credential = $cred
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credential
Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector
$SFBSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $credential
Import-PSSession $SFBSession
```